# TLS version and HTTP supported in production

Tags: security, http, tls

We have not activated the update '**TLS1.1 for HTTPS**' in our production org.

So which version of TLS are right now supported by it? I mean does it support only TLS1.0 or it would support TLS 1.1?

And I have no idea what is the relation of HTTPS and TLS, it would be great if someone could enlighten me which version TLS is mendatory for HTTPS and which are for HTTP at present before this 1.1 update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are supported** regardless of when you enable this critical update. TLS 1.0 will not be automatically disabled in your `Production Instance` until **March 4, 2017, at 9:30 AM PST**. Until that date, you can still use the old TLS 1.0 protocol. Note that the date for automatic disablement in `Sandbox Instances` has already passed.

See [TLS 1.0 Disablement Critical Update Console (CRUC) Setting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=TLS-1-0-Disablement-Critical-Update-Console-CRUC-Setting):

> ```
> Service                 TLS 1.0 Disablement Auto-Activation Date
> Sandbox Instance        June 25, 2016, at 9:30 AM PDT (16:30 UTC)
> Production Instances    March 4, 2017, at 9:30 AM PST (17:30 UTC)
>
> Login.salesforce.com, other services**    Early 2017
> ```
>
> <sup><sub>** Other services includes the following: test.salesforce.com, www.salesforce.com, help.salesforce.com, success.salesforce.com, branded login (*.cloudforce.com), Live Agent, UMPS/Chatter Messenger and Email.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks Adrian for these deatils. But could you tell me what will happen if I am using an application with TLS 1.1 right now? And right now i mean before enabling this update.

Comment: Yes 1.1 and 1.2 are of course supported. It will just be required to use one of them once you enable the update. See my edits.

Answer (score 4):

**TLS** is the transport layer which encrypts your connection while commenting between Server - Client. So, eventually there have been cryptographic improvements in TLS. Previously it was TLS 1.0 which most of the browser and server support. After this new improvement came which is TLS 1.1 (TLS 1.2 is current)

The basic difference is TLS 1.0 supported the downgrade negotiation which was pleasing thing for Hackers/Attackers/Bot.

**HTTPS** is protocol which can create connection between Server - Client using SSL.TLS 1.0/1.2 combination. HTTPS leverage these security layers to establish a secure connection. If any of the party doesn't support the enforced security, it throw exception which now a day most of the servers getting when connected to Salesforce.

**Salesforce Productions and Sandbox** support TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 and enforce basic TLS 1.1 in sandbox. Below this is not supported now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ashwani for the deatils of TLS and HTTPS. But are you sure that TLS1.1 will work on production right now?

Comment: Yes, I have recently implemented it over a enterprise server integrated with Salesforce Enterprise edition production. It should work smoothly. However, it is more of a server administrator thing. As a Salesforce guy, you don't need to do anything.